# how to use rtrim in Apex?

Tags: apex, error, string

I need to remove the trailing spaces from a String. However, when I try that in Execute Anonymous window with the below test apex code, I am getting the below error message.

```
String testString = 'ABCD124  ';
System.debug('Trimmed string = ' + rtrim(testString,' '));

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void rtrim(string, string)
```

I need to retain the leading spaces, if there are any. So, I can't use the trim() method.

I also tried without the second parameter, and it did not work either.

Can someone help?

The regular expression worked, but I have problems related to this. I getting a response from REST API with some account details and I am comparing the old and new values before updating the account. Some sample code snippet is below.

```
if (((aRec.D__c != null && aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != (aUpdRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')) ||
((aRec.P__c != null && aRec.P__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != (aUpdRec.P__c != null && aUpdRec.P__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')))
```

However, the value of D__c could be null in some cases and it is throwing the below error message.

```
Logical Operator can only be applied to boolean
```

It appears that the || operation is causing the issue when the values are null. When aRec.D__c is null and aUpdRec.D__c is null, we are comparing null != null and I am not sure the result of this. I guess it is not a boolean and hence getting the error message.

Any ideas to fix this?

**EDIT**:

I was able to fix it, by adding the statements before the if condition:

```
if (aRec.D__c != null)
   aRec.D__c = aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'');
```

**NEW EDIT**:

I have couple of fields on the accounts (D__c, P__c and some more). I make a callout to a third party webservice and get the new values for these fields on the account. I need to trim the trailing spaces on the fields before comparing. In short, I am trying to evaluate the below expression.

```
if ((aRec.D__c == null && aUpdRec.D__c != null) || 
    (aRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c == null) || 
    (aRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c != null &&  
     aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') !=  
     aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'')) || ==> repeat for other fields like P__c.
```

When I use the above expression, I am getting the message "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: NULL, Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a regular expression to remove spaces with [String.replaceAll(regExp, replacement)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

```java
String regExp = '\\s+$';
String test = '  Hello   World     ';
System.debug('Output: ' + test.replaceAll(regExp, '') + '-- End'); // Output:   Hello   World-- End
```

---

You have a problem with parentheses.
You wrote:
`aRec.D__c != null && aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != (aUpdRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, ''))`.
I'm going to add parentheses to explain what happens: `(aRec.D__c != null) && (aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != (aUpdRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')))`.
The problem is here: `(aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != (aUpdRec.D__c != null && aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')))`. The left operand is a String, the second one is an expression that evaluates to a boolean. That's why you got "Logical Operator can only be applied to boolean"

Try this:

```
if ( (aRec.D__c?.replaceAll(regExp,'') != aUpdRec.D__c?.replaceAll(regExp, '')) ||
  (aRec.P__c?.replaceAll(regExp,'') != aUpdRec.P__c?.replaceAll(regExp, '')) )
```

Update: Using the [?. operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) the if-blcok will be executed whether `aRec.D__c` or `aRec.P__c` will differ from their *UpdRec* relatives. I.E. `aRec.D__c` is null and `aUpdRec.D__c` is not and viceversa, or their values aren't equal.

Please take a look at [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).
If you could state what you would like to achieve, we could provide more useful answers.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I have another problem related to this code. My sample code is below. Will update in original post

Comment: @BalajiPooruli I've update the answer. There was a problem with parentheses in your `if`

Comment: @RubanDG, Thanks for your answer. The if statements that you have may or may not work as there are chances where either one of them could be null. The solution I have given in the original post seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli since those statements are in AND, if any resolves to false, the following will not be evaluated, therefore there will not be a NullPointerException, because it will evaluate `aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')` only if both `aRec.D__c` and `aUpdRec.D__c` are not null. The same goes with `aRec.P__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != aUpdRec.P__c.replaceAll(regExp, '')`

Comment: There will not be a NullPointerException, but if aRec.D__c is not null and aUpdRec.D__c is null, the whole expression will not be evaluated and hence we will be missing that update. Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @BalajiPooruli That's right, (aRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp,'') != aUpdRec.D__c.replaceAll(regExp, '') would not be evaluated jumping to check the second statement, the one about `P__c`. Since you never posted the code inside the `if` block, I had doubt about that logic, that's why I wrote "I don't know if this is the logic that you need" suggesting to provide more info about your goal. Now it's clearer and I'm going to update the answer

Comment: Thanks, I have selected your answer as the best answer.

Comment: @RubanDG, I am still having the problem using ? operator. It doesn't appear to be working when all variables on aUpdRec values are null. I will edit my original post by adding what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: It was a problem with parenthesis only. I was able to add extra () to resolve the error message. Currently testing the job.